# match "--word" and "--no-word" but not "---word"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following RegExp:

```
^--([\w|-]+)
```

I'd like to match

```
--word
--no-word
```

But not:

```
---word
----word
```

Comment: What about `--in-the-hall`? What about `--some--word`? What about `--trailing-`?

Answer (score 5):

Change your expression to

```
^--(\w[-\w]*)
```

This requires at least *one* word character after the two dashes, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/J3qNsg/2).

Please note that the character class itself already forms an alternation, so unless you also want to allow `|` somewhere in the string you do not need it within the class.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

The [**word boundary**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) would help, but you should also remove `|` since this symbol inside `[...]` is not an alternation operator, but a regular pipe symbol:

```
^--\b([\w-]+)
```

## Demo

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HjGne2/1).

## Details

- `^` - [start of a string](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `--` - two `-` chars
- `\b` - a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) that requires a *word* char right after the `--`
- `([\w-]+)` - [Capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1: one or more (due to `+` quantifier) word chars or `-` symbols (as `[\w-]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching any char(s) / classes of chars defined inside the square brackets).

## Demo

```js
var strs = ["--word", "--no-word", "---word", "----word"];
var rx = /^--\b([\w-]+)/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works here, I'm checking for an option hyphen in between the two word character clauses.

```
^--(\w+[-]?\w+)
```

Comment: While it works, the expression is a) not that effective and b) you do not need to put the hyphen in a class, `-?` would works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to identify command line instructions, is that right?

Try this:

```
^--\w+(-\w+)*
```

Gets:

```
--word
--no-word-word-word-word
--no-word
```

But not:

```
---word
----word
--word-
--word--word
```